# Show And Hide List of names With two classes with radio button jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle

I have a list of names with male and female classes. i added male/female radio buttons to this page. when i click on male radio button all names with class=male will display and and vise versa. can u suggest a good jquery method for this.

```
<input id="male" value="Male" type="radio" checked="checked">
<input id="female" value="Female" type="radio"> 

<div class="Male">male name</div>
<div class="female">female name</div>
<div class="Male">male name</div>
```

Comment: [hide()](http://api.jquery.com/hide), [show()](http://api.jquery.com/show) and [:not()](http://api.jquery.com/not-selector)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need JavaScript for this. Just set

```css
.male, .female { display: none }
#male:checked ~ .male, #female:checked ~ .female { display: block }
```

## [demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/3781735)

Also add a `name` attribute with the same value for both your radio buttons (`name="gender"` in this case) to make sure they do behave like radio buttons and cannot be checked at once.

```html
<input id="male" value="Male" name="gender" type="radio" checked>
<input id="female" value="Female" name="gender" type="radio">
```

Be aware that in order for this to work, the divs with the names must follow the radio inputs in the HTML.

Comment: Your (quite clever) approach works for the OP's code as given; however, if his actual code is less simple and those elements aren't siblings, your CSS will not work.

Comment: thanks for ur answer, but this not working for me, my names list is loading dynamically with html5 localstorage, class values(male,female) and names are loaded from localstorage. and my checkbox buttons within field sets

Comment: <fieldset class="switch blue" style="margin-left:268px;">
 <legend></legend>

  <input id="male" name="gender" value="Male" type="radio"  checked>  
  <label for="male">Male</label>

  <input id="female" name="gender" value="Female" type="radio"> 
  <label for="female">Female</label>

  <span class="switch-button"></span>
</fieldset>

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="male" value="Male" type="radio" onclick="doaction('Male,female')" checked>

    <input id="female" value="Female"  onclick="doaction('female,Male')"  type="radio"> 

    <div class="Male">male name</div>
    <div class="female">female name</div>
    <div class="Male">male name</div>

    <script>

    function doaction(z,z2)
    {
    $("." + z2).hide();
    $("." + z).show();

    }

</script>
```